# Why would you sret from machine mode?

Tags: riscv

In RISC-V, when would it be useful to be able to `sret` from a machine mode trap handler? I can't quite figure it out.

As far as I can see the only difference from using `mret` is that it will check `SPP` instead of `MPP`. But `SPP` is set when entering the supervisor mode trap handler, not the machine mode one.

Answer (score 0):

I got a good answer from someone on the mailing list:

> The utility (or lack thereof) of executing SRET within M-mode isn’t the reason why the various xRET instructions have different opcodes. The reason is classical (trap-and-emulate) virtualization, where you don’t want the behavior of an instruction to silently differ based on current privilege mode. You want it to either do what software wants, or raise a trap so the VMM can intervene. It would be a virtualization hole when classically virtualizing M-mode software within S-mode if executing MRET didn’t trap but instead performed an SRET.